# Reading complex JSON ARRAY in angular

Tags: json, angular

This is the first time I am working in angular. I am not sure whether this is complex or simple.I want to read the below JSON ARRAY and render it in a complex table.Can some one help me how to read or access the different submodules in it.I can't give exact details like how to render or the table structure as it is too complex to explain rendering this json on table.Can some one just help me how to access different elements of this below JSON ARRAY.

Need to use *ngFor to loop through in my table

```
Response =
{
            "userId" : "",
            "module" : "Opportunity",
            "moduleDetails" : [
            {
            "moduleElements" : [
                {
                    "elementName" : "Account Name",
                    "elementValue" : "155744"           

                }
                {
                    "elementName" : "oppty owner",
                    "elementValue" : "Europe"
                },
                {
                    "elementName" : "products",
                    "elementValue" : "June 10,2010"
                },
                {
                    "elementName" : "Dom",
                    "elementValue : "8056568"


                },
                {
                    "elementName" : "ASAP  ",
                    "elementValue" : "wer"
                },
                {
                    "elementName" : "Price scenario status",
                    "elementValue" : "$243.00"

                }


                ],
                "moduleMilestones" : [
                                            {
                                                "elementName": "statusId",
                                                "elementValue": "60"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "elementName": "sstId",
                                                "elementValue": "NA"
                                            }
                                        ],
                "subModules" : [
                    {
                        "subModule" : "Solution",
                        "subModuleDetails" : [
                            {
                                    "subModuleElements" : [
                                        {
                                            "elementName" : "solutionName",
                                            "elementValue" : "112233"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "elementName" : "solutionId",
                                            "elementValue" : "SameeraSolution"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "elementName" : "dealType",
                                            "elementValue" : "AVPN"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "elementName" : "startDate",
                                            "elementValue" : "28-Jul-1992"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "elementName" : "endDate",
                                            "elementValue" : "28-Jul-2020"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "elementName" : "status",
                                            "elementValue" : "Reaeneration"
                                        }
                                        ],
                                        "subModuleMilestones" : [
                                            {
                                                "elementName": "statusId",
                                                "elementValue": "60"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "elementName": "supstId",
                                                "elementValue": "NA"
                                            }
                                        ]

                            },
                            {
                                    "subModuleElements" : [
                                        {
                                            "elementName" : "soId",
                                            "elementValue" : "332211"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "elementName" : "same",
                                            "elementValue" : "SameeraSolution"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "elementName" : "dealType",
                                            "elementValue" : "An"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "elementName" : "startDate",
                                            "elementValue" : "28-Jul-1992"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "elementName" : "endDate",
                                            "elementValue" : "28-Jul-2020"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "elementName" : "status",
                                            "elementValue" : "Reneration"
                                        },
                                        "subModuleMilestones" : [
                                            {
                                                "elementName": "statusId",
                                                "elementValue": "60"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "elementName": "sustId",
                                                "elementValue": "NA"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    ]
                            }
                        ]   
                    }
                ]


        }
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const theDeets = Response.moduleDetails // accessing object property

const firstDeet = theDeets[0] // accessing array element using index

const secondElementValue = firstDeet[1].elementValue // chaining both methods

console.log(secondElementValue) // prints “Europe”
```

From here you’ll want to look up Array methods and Object methods to do more stuff with the data, but this is the answer to how you access stuff.